# Maven dependency based on argument

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, arguments

I have a Maven project with a number of modules. When building, I have an argument that determines which directory config files and such are copied from, depending on environment it will be running in - ie UAT, DEV, TEST, etc. I do not want to use profiles. Now, I want to package all integration tests into a separate jar that can be executed from command line as well as in integration-test phase. Basically there will be only one test class with one method that does something like

```
 Class.forName("...").getMethod("main").invoke(null, args);
```

Only problem, is that since I do not want to use profiles Id have to add/remove the dependency on the test solution jar depending on if I want to run integration tests or not. I would like to do something like

```
 mvn clean install -Denv=IT
```

and let it be. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Is there any reason for not using profiles?

Comment: Making the pom shorter, simpler and prettier. Also, I suffix the build 'type' to each artifact/dependency so there is no confusion what environment its for. As in no chance a test build will be sent to production or something like that

Answer (score 0):

The standard mechanism for running different kinds of build in Maven is to use profiles (Maven is a highly opinionated build framework, so you are forced to play by its rules)

Your also appear to be building binaries to match the system you intend to deploy. This is generally a bad idea, you are better advised to look at some mechanism that allows the run-time configuration of your application. (In J2EE there is JNDI, but could be just a simple property file). This allows you to certify a single binary that ideally is pushed into a shared repository for sharing between development, test and production.

Comment: Configuration is done via .property files. They are packaged into the jars on the class path for every module. They basically act as 'defaults' if an external custom configuration is not provided. Idea is I think/hope external configuration will be only provided in production, and would like deployment for testing and development to be as simple as copying one archive. Also, try to achieve maximum amount of standardization and consistency across every project.